# Lightbox library does not connect (ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

I connect lightbox library (gem 'lightbox2-rails') trough the gemfile. Making all steps described at https://github.com/gavinkflam/lightbox2-rails
But after starting the server and trying to find the lightbox object through the console, I get an error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: lightbox is not defined at <anonymous>: 1: 1`
Please tell me where is the error?
Gemfile contains gem 'jquery-rails'

Comment: I have tried but it still works fine, can I have your repo?

Comment: @NinhLe Thank you very mutch! There is a repo: https://github.com/bshourse/TestGallery

Comment: Everything works well if I download the latest release separately (js, css files) from here:
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/releases

If you have time, please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the first case when I connect the lightbox through the gem

Comment: Rails 6 using webpacker to manage their assets, so the way in the tutorial doesn't work any more